# Don't use jQuery DOM changes when printing

Tags: javascript, css, dom, printing, fullpage.js

**Update:** CSS solution below.

I'm using the [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) jQuery plugin which unfortunately also affects the printing of the webpage, only displaying the current viewport display and its sibling.

The problem I have is that the print command uses the DOM (obviously), but the plugin has already made inline CSS changes in the DOM. Is there a way to disable the DOM changes for `print`?

This doesn't work, but here's my idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(@media !print) { // PS: Not real code!
        $('#fullpage').fullpage();
    }
});
```

**------ CSS solution -------**

[Praveen's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32045211/108909) led me on the right course. The CSS needed to override the fullpage.js inline styles are:

```
/* Override javascript inline styles */
html,
body {
    overflow: visible !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

.fullpage-wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
    transform: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}

.fp-section {
    height: auto !important;
}

.fp-slidesContainer {
    width: auto !important;
    transition: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
}

.fp-slides,
.fp-slides * {
    position: static !important;
}

.fp-slide {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Why would one care about printing nowadays?

Comment: @OddDev Because of usability. Even if you or I never print, doesn't mean others don't.

Comment: Even if you or I never use IE6, doesn't mean others don't. Add infinite items to this list ;)

Comment: Only one item on the IE6 list ;-) All content is accessible in older IEs with separate fallback CSS, not very dissimilar to print.css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this in your CSS:

Hiding the full page slides:

```css
.fp-slides {
  display: none;
}
```

Or making them static, as this would do the stuff by rendering the contents normally:

```css
.fp-slides, .fp-slides * {
  position: static !important;
  /* I don't like putting !important,
     but there is no other way to override the inline styles without this!*/
}
```

Else, you can specify the stylesheet to apply for only `screen` as the media:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fullpage.css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: This led me in the right direction - the answer was in the CSS, not in the javascript. I've amended my post to include the solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a flag and set it true when the printing function is called:

```
var flag = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(flag === false) {
    // all your code
  }


  function toPrint() {
    flag = true;
    window.print();
  }
});
```